# GNU Smalltalk - Formatting output and disabling GC messages

Tags: gnu, smalltalk

How do I disable garbage collection messages with GNU Smalltalk 3.0.5 stable? Also, is there a way to remove the quote marks output when outputting strings?

```
Ex:
'test' printNl.
```

prints

`'test'`

rather than

`test`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Garbage collection messages are disabled automatically when you use your program as a script (i.e. with `gst -f`), or you can use `--no-gc-message` (short option `-g`).

`printNl` is a programmer-oriented printing message.  To print without quotes use `display`/`displayNl`.  Similarly, characters will be printed without dollar signs.